# How to pass row value in update from select statement?

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-update

I need some help with a simple (simple in PostgreSQL, but I need in SQL Server 2008) update from select statement. I don't know how to pass "values" from rows as variables to the select statement in from clause. This is what i've done.

```
DECLARE @OldAnswerValue INT = 7;
DECLARE @Type INT =3;
SELECT A.Id as NewAnswer
FROM tblEvaluationAnswers A
WHERE A.AnswerValue=
    CASE @OldAnswerValue
    WHEN 0 THEN 1
    WHEN 1 THEN 2
    ...
    WHEN 9 THEN 5
    END
AND AnswerType=@Type
```

and my update will look like

```
UPDATE transPersonEvaluation
SET UserAnswer=PEA.NewAnswer
FROM ( ) as PEA --here the select statement inside from
```

but I don't know how to pass @OldAnswerValue and @Type as parameters into the from clause. This values are extracted from each row of transPersonEvaluation wich I am updating.
In PostgreSQL I think it is like

```
UPDATE transPersonEvaluation PE
SET UserAnswer=PEA.NewAnswer
FROM (
    SELECT A.Id as NewAnswer
    FROM tblEvaluationAnswers A ... where A.AnswerType=PE.AnswerType) as PEA;
```

but it is throwing syntax error on sql server 2008.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UPDATE from SELECT using SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in sql server your query would look like this.

```
UPDATE PE
SET PE.UserAnswer=PEA.NewAnswer
FROM transPersonEvaluation PE
JOIN 
(
    SELECT A.Id as NewAnswer
    FROM tblEvaluationAnswers A ... ) as PEA ON PEA.AnswerType = PE.AnswerType;
```